# QProcess not terminating on different PC

Tags: c++, qt

I have a strange issue with QProcess.  I'm running Qt 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (on a HP workstation Xeon based PC).  The following bit of code executes and terminates properly (process takes about 20 seconds to complete) on PC1.  I take the code over to PC2, also running Qt 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (VMWare on OSX Mavericks), and the finished(int) signal is never emitted (the qDebug prints waiting forever, and seemingly much faster than on the correctly working PC).  Anyone have an idea on what the problem could be?  The run() function is invoked via a QPushButton signal, and the slots all properly execute on PC1, but are never executed on PC2.

```
void VaredWindow::run()
{
    //! update the GUI to let the user know we're running now
    txtOutput->clear();
    txtStatus->setText(QString("Running ") + appSelect->currentText() + QString("..."));
    txtStatus->repaint();
    txtOutput->repaint();
    qApp->processEvents();

    //! create and start up the app process
    proc = new QProcess(this);
    int appNum = appSelect->currentIndex();
    QString app = getAppName(appNum);
    QStringList args = getAppArgs(appNum);

    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readStdout()));
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(readStderror()));
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(procFinished()));

    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor); // make a spinny thingy
    proc->setWorkingDirectory(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
    proc->start(app, args);

    while (!proc->waitForFinished(500))
    {
        qDebug() << "Waiting";
    }
}
```

Also of note, it's worked properly on two machines, and the odd behavior on two machines, they are as follows:

- PC1 (works), Xeon Workstation w/Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
- PC2 (doesn't work), Macbook Pro VMWare w/Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
- PC3 (works), Macbook Pro VMWare w/Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- PC4 (doesn't work), Macbook Pro VMWare w/Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: My guess would be that on PC2 and PC4 the start() call is failing, and that is why finished(int) signal is never emitted -- the process can't finish if it never starts.  Of course Process::start() doesn't have any return value so it's not clear how to know if it worked or not; but in any case I'd suggest looking at what string is contained in "app" and seeing if an executable with that name actually exists (and has read and execute permissions set) on those machines.

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to connect the QProcess started() and error() signals up to two different slots in your program, and see if either of those signals are being emitted after you call start().  Note that blocking in waitForFinished() might prevent those signals from being emitted, so it would be better to redesign your program so that it doesn't block that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Jeremy.  I'll give those ideas a look.

Comment: It looks as though the difference in behavior was a result of incorrect PATHs set up on the odd machines, but what's strange is the way they errored.  I moved the proc->waitForFinished(500) to a slot and even though it's supposed to spin every 500ms, it spins on the odd machines as if there's no wait time whatsoever.  This is even after I fixed the pathing issue.

Comment: Also just to add, the started() signal is fired by the QProcess in question.